# jquery modal opened on click on a hyperlink vanishes immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

When i click on the "Register" hyperlink(placed on the login modal form), my register modal pops up but, disappears immediately. I am noob at jquery and javascript so this doesn't make sense. I tried adding the following code(which doesn't work either) instead of what i have on my main code.

```
    $('.message a').click(function(){
        modal.style.display =  "none";
        $("#RegisterModal").css("display","block");
    })
```

my main code is:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var modal = document.getElementById('LoginModal');
    var modalreg = document.getElementById('RegisterModal');
    var login = document.getElementById("butn");
    var reg = document.getElementById("butn0");
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    var span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];

    login.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    reg.onclick = function() {
        modalreg.style.display = "block";
    }


    $('.message a').click(function(){ //message is the class of the //paragraph containing the link
        modalreg.style.display = "block";
    })

    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    span1.onclick = function() {
        modalreg.style.display = "none";
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target.id == 'LoginModal') {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
        if (event.target.id == 'RegisterModal') {
            modalreg.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

</script>
```

here's my whole html code:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">
<title>1Tag</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body style="background-color: white;">
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-image: url('full.jpg'); min-width: 101.2%;">

<div>
    <header>
       <div>
           <button class="button button1" id="butn0">Register</button>
           <button class="button button2" id="butn">Login</button>
       </div>
       <h1>1Tag</h1>
    </header>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content" style="background-image: url('3.jpg');">
    <span onclick="document.getElementById('close').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal" style="margin-right: 2%">&times;</span>
      <form class="modal-content" style="background-color: transparent;" action="" method="post">
        <div style="background-color: transparent; margin-left: 50px; margin-top: -10px; margin-right: 0; margin-bottom: 0; width: 400px;">
          <h3 style="color: #acacac; font-size: 30px; font-family: Helvetica Neue;">Sign In</h3>
          <p style="font-family: Helvetica Neue; color: #acacac;">Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
          <hr>
          <label for="Username"><b style="font-family: Helvetica Neue; color: #acacac;">Username : </b></label>
          <input type="name" placeholder="Enter Username" name="name" required>

          <label for="email"><b style="font-family: Helvetica Neue; color: #acacac;">Email : </b></label>
          <input type="mail" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

          <label for="psw"><b style="font-family: Helvetica Neue; color: #acacac;">Password : </b></label>
          <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" style="margin-bottom:15px; color: #acacac;"> <b style="font-family: Helvetica Neue; color: #acacac;">Remember me</b>
          </label>

          <p class="message">Are you not registered?<a href="" style="color:dodgerblue">Register</a>.</p>

          <div class="clearfix">
            <button type="button" id="cancel" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'" class="button3" style="margin-right: 5%; 
                background-color: #333;
                padding: 6px 16px;
                font-size: 14px;">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="button2" style=" padding:6px 16px; font-size: 14px;" name="login">Sign In</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myReg" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content" style="background-image: url('3.jpg'); overflow-y: initial !important;">
    <span onclick="document.getElementById('close').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal" style="margin-right: 2%">&times;</span>
      <form class="modal-content" style="background-color: transparent;" action="http://localhost/fuckinFromSkratch/register.php" method="post">
        <div style="background-color: transparent; margin-left: 50px; margin-top: -10px; margin-right: 0; margin-bottom: 0; width: 400px;">
          <h3 style="color: #acacac; font-size: 30px; font-family: Helvetica Neue;">Sign Up</h3>
          <p style="font-family: Helvetica Neue; color: #acacac;">Please fill in this form to log into your account.</p>
          <hr>
          <div style=" height: 250px; overflow-y: auto;">
              <label for="Username"><b style="font-family: Helvetica Neue; color: #acacac;">Username : </b></label>
              <input type="name" placeholder="Enter Username" id="uname" name="name" required>

              <label for="email"><b style="font-family: Helvetica Neue; color: #acacac;">Email : </b></label>
              <input type="mail" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

              <label for="psw"><b style="font-family: Helvetica Neue; color: #acacac;">Password : </b></label>
              <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

              <label for="psw2"><b style="font-family: Helvetica Neue; color: #acacac;">Confirm Password : </b></label>
              <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="psw2" required>

              <label for="gender"><b style="font-family: Helvetica Neue; color: #acacac;">Gender(Male/Female) : </b></label>
              <input type="name" placeholder="Enter Your Gender" id="gen" name="gender">

              <label for="dtb"><b style="font-family: Helvetica Neue; color: #acacac;">Birth Date : </b></label>
              <input type="name" placeholder="Enter Date of Birth" id="bday" name="dtb">
          </div>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" style="margin-bottom:15px; color: #acacac;"> <b style="font-family: Helvetica Neue; color: #acacac;">Remember me</b>
          </label>

          <p style="font-family: Helvetica Neue; color: #acacac;">By creating an account you agree to our <a href="" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

          <div class="clearfix">
            <button type="button" id="cancel2" onclick="document.getElementById('myReg').style.display='none'" class="button3" style="margin-right: 5%; 
                background-color: #333;
                padding: 6px 16px;
                font-size: 14px;">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="button2" style=" padding:6px 16px; font-size: 14px;" name="reg" id="register">Register </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    var modalreg = document.getElementById('myReg');
    var btn = document.getElementById("butn");
    var btn0 = document.getElementById("butn0");
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    var span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];

    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    btn0.onclick = function() {
        modalreg.style.display = "block";
    }


    $('.message a').click(function(){
        modalreg.style.display = "block";
    })

    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    span1.onclick = function() {
        modalreg.style.display = "none";
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target.id == 'myModal') {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
        if (event.target.id == 'myReg') {
            modalreg.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the css portion of the modal:

```
    .message{
      font-family: Helvetica Neue; 
      color: #acacac;
    }

    .modal {
     display: none; 
     position: fixed; 
     z-index: 1; 
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%; 
     height: 100%; 
     background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); 
   }

   /* Modal Content/Box */
   .modal-content {
     background-color: transparent;
     margin: 3% auto;
     padding: 5px 5px ;
     width: 470px;
     height: 530px;
   }

   /* The Close Button */
   .close {
     color: #aaa;
     float: right;
     font-size: 28px;
     font-weight: bold;
   }

   .close:hover,
   .close:focus {
     color: black;
     text-decoration: none;
     cursor: pointer;
   }

   /* input fields */
   input[type=mail], input[type=password], input[type=name] {
     width: 60%;
     padding: 9px;
     margin: 5px 0 16px 0;
     display: table;
     border: none;
     background: #f1f1f1;
   }

   /* when the inputs get focus */
   input[type=mail]:focus, input[type=password]:focus, 
   input[type=name]:focus {
     background-color: #ddd;
     outline: none;
   }

   hr {
     width: 90%;
     border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     margin-left: -3px;
     color: #acacac;
   }

   .clearfix::after {
     content: "";
     clear: both;
     display: table;
   }

   /* Change styles for cancel button and signup button on extra small 
    screens 
   */
   @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
     .cancelbtn, .signupbtn {
       width: 100%;
     }
   }
```

Comment: Perhaps you have overlap in html elements which open and close modal. Please add your html code.

Comment: added the html code

Comment: id `cancel` duplicated, id must be unique

Comment: You also have two `<head></head>`. Remove the one wrapping your theme.css

Comment: changed it.. help me on solving this annoying problem too :(

Comment: Please provide your CSS as well. Without it modals are not modals in fact and they don't disappear as you described

Comment: Ok, just tested it. The modal doesn't disappear, unless I click cancel or close or outside modal.

Comment: also i'm talking about the modal that pops up after u click on the 'Register' hyperlink in the login form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, didn't understand the target of issue at first. Actualy, your modal doesn't vanish. This is just your page reloaded after you click `<a>`. Solution:

```
$('.message a').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  modalreg.style.display = "block";
  modal.style.display = "none";
});
```